# Changes of two different branches done in a single branch

Tags: git, github

I had two different branches, let's say branchA and branchB. I checked out to branchB and made changes in featureB. In addition to featureB, I made the required changes of featureA too! Now I want only the featureB changes to be pushed in branchB, and only the featureA changes to be pushed to branchA. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You have this.

```
      C - FB - FA [branchB]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      D - E [branchA]
```

A, B, C, etc are just some commits. FA and FB represent the commits for feature A and feature B.

You want this.

```
      C - FB [branchB]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      D - E - FA [branchA]
```

There's several ways to handle this. Here's one.

First, [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the feature A changes into branchA. This will copy the commit. There may be conflicts.

```
git checkout branchA
git cherry-pick FA

      C - FB - FA [branchB]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      D - E - FA [branchA]
```

Then eliminate the commit (s) from branchB using an interactive rebase.

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase -i master
```

An editor will come up. Delete the lines with the offending commits and Git will rewrite the remaining commits in branchB on top of master.

```
      C - FB [branchB]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      D - E - FA [branchA]
```

See [Rewriting History in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I have not yet committed the changes. All the changes in featureA and featureB are local to my system, and I am on branchB. What can I do?

Comment: @Deepanshu When you say "you have not yet committed the changes" do you mean you haven't ***pushed*** the changes? That's good, this would be a bit harder if they were already pushed. Follow the answer to fix your local repository and then push your branches as normal.